# Why is the solution to Count number of unique paths from source to destination in 4 directions" not dynamic programming?

Tags: algorithm, path

For the problem "Find the number of unique paths from source to destination in a 2d grid. You can move in 4 directions and only to positions with a 1 in them. You may not move to a position more than once."

For example in the below grid, the number of unique paths from top left to bottom right, moving in 4 directions is 4.

```
[ 1 1 1 1 ]
[ 1 1 0 1 ]
[ 0 1 0 1 ]
[ 1 1 1 1 ]
Solutions:
[ * * * * ]      [ * * 1 1 ]      [ * 1 1 1 ]      [ * * * * ]
[ 1 1 0 * ]      [ 1 * 0 1 ]      [ * * 0 1 ]      [ * * 0 * ]
[ 0 1 0 * ]      [ 0 * 0 1 ]      [ 0 * 0 1 ]      [ 0 1 0 * ]
[ 1 1 1 * ]      [ 1 * * * ]      [ 1 * * * ]      [ 1 1 1 * ]
```

Is this not a dynamic programming problem because we can't cache the number of ways from source to a point because there are exponential number of ways to reach that point?

Or is it possibly because to reach [x][y], we have to take number of sum of number of ways from [x][y-1], [x-1][y], [x+1][y], [x][y+1] but those directions would also have to take number of ways from [x][y], for example [x][y-1] would take ways from [x-1][y-1], [x][y], etc.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add a point to a path if the path already contains the point. So caching paths from `{x, y}` to the end doesn't help you count paths from some neighbour of `{x, y}`. For each neighbour, you need the number of paths not including that point, which will usually be a different  number for each neighbour